# Yii - Google Maps Extension (EGMap) - Onclick Event on a Circle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, yii

I have some GMap extension in my current project.

I have a few coordinate that I want to show on the map in a circle form.

Here is some of my code:

```
Yii::import('ext.egmap.EGMap.*');
$gMap = new EGMap();
$gMap->setJsName('map');
$gMap->zoom = 10;
$gMap->setCenter(2.600180, 98.805609);

$circle = new EGMapCircle(new EGMapCoord(2.338106, 99.061119));
$circle->radius = 300;
$circle->addHtmlInfoWindow(new EGMapInfoWindow('Hey! First Circle!'));
$gMap->addCircle($circle);

$circle = new EGMapCircle(new EGMapCoord(2.453943, 98.979175));
$circle->radius = 280.9;
$circle->addHtmlInfoWindow(new EGMapInfoWindow('Hey! Second Circle!'));
$gMap->addCircle($circle);

$gMap->renderMap();
```

I'm really new with this extension, but I really confused in how to add some "CLICK" event within each circle.
For some purpose, when this circle clicked, it will have to do some Ajax POST into another Controller in my Yii Project like,

```
$circle->addEvent('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controller/method",
        data: // "CIRCLE COORDINATE",
        // Another statement
    })
});
$gMap->addCircle($circle);
```

Is there any idea for this one?
Thanks in advance!